# gnuplot: Control the size of circles in a scatter chart

Tags: gnuplot

I need to produce a scatter chart from a two-column comma-separated text file:

```
gnuplot> set style fill transparent solid .5 noborder
gnuplot> plot "corr.csv" using 0:1 with circles lc rgb "blue"
```

Here is the output:

[image]

However I want something like that:
[image]

I want to scale the circles up with the values in the x-axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of *scaling*/increasing circle size as ***x*** values get bigger:

Sample `input.dat` file contents (with 2 columns):

```
1 1
1 2
2 3
2 4
3 3
4 3
5 4
6 4
7 7
8 4
8 5
9 5
```

---

Via command line in interactive mode:

```
$ gnuplot
gnuplot> set style fill transparent solid .5 noborder
gnuplot> set xrange [0:GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX]
gnuplot> set yrange [0:GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX]
gnuplot> plot "input.dat" u 1:2:(.03*($1)) w circles lc rgb "blue"
```

---

The output:
[image]